# Storing different variables in one variable

Tags: modelica, openmodelica

I try to write a code in modelica. I calculate a value for 4 different areas, which are cpm_links for[1:3], cpm_oben[4:6] for, cpm_rechts for[7:9] , cpm_oben for[10:12]. Then I want to store these 4 values in a one variable which is cpm for[1:12]. How should I write a code so that all these 4 variables will be stored in cpm?

```
  cpm_links[1:n_Kapazitaten]=cp_Kunststoff*m_link[1:n_Kapazitaten];
  cpm_oben[1:n_Kapazitaten]=cp_Kunststoff*m_oben[1:n_Kapazitaten];
  cpm_rechts[1:n_Kapazitaten]=cp_Kunststoff*m_link[1:n_Kapazitaten];
  cpm_unten[1:n_Kapazitaten]=cp_Kunststoff*m_oben[1:n_Kapazitaten];
```

Comment: See: https://specification.modelica.org/master/arrays.html#array-concatenation
You can use array slicing or array concatenation for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `cat` function to combine multiple arrays into one. See recent Stack Overflow question [How to insert arguments of a vector inside another vector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64333964/how-to-insert-arguments-of-a-vector-inside-another-vector)